# Gmail showing "Authorized App" in my recent activity list

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

I have a fairly complex password and I have 2 factor auth enabled but I'm seeing in my recent activity list:

```
Authorized Application (532713016892-ev29m8tv9gejefcvvv1o3coj5bhkc1ar.apps.googleusercontent.com) Hide details
OAuth Domain Name:
532713016892-ev29m8tv9gejefcvvv1o3coj5bhkc1ar.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

It's coming from the same IP as my "Mobile" and "Browser" activity logs. The only authorized Apps in my list are Chrome.  Does anyone know what `532713016892-ev29m8tv9gejefcvvv1o3coj5bhkc1ar.apps.googleusercontent.com` resolves to?  Was thinking it might be the Gmail iPhone app but wouldn't that show up as "Mobile"?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issues have been [reported before](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10983585?hl=en) and again. It is used by Google most likely in connection to some app you use on your phone.
Don't worry. Nobody is hacking your phone.

[image: Google tracker]

Answer (score -1):

Might not be someone hacking your phone.  However they were mine.  They gain access through your Gmail accounts and go through the back door of the web.  I do not know all the computer lingo or terminology, but my case was proven.  Once inside they can download and hide apps from Google play store or or even samsung galaxy.  They are even appearing as my IP address and my Android s10+ . When in fact they were operating from an iPhone 7 12_1   they got into my PayPal account. Used my credit card information and downloaded Microsoft connect to your PC.  Then they had full access and control. They were able to view messages and still show unopened from my actual device.
In your Google search history and analytics be on the lookout for fingerprints such as com.google.android.camera or messages or any other number of access points.
I know and understand these domains will normally show up in your regular history. However I put my theory to the test and stay logged out of my apps for a couple days and still there was history accumulating.
Was finally able to catch them, when I too down loaded connect to my PC app to my actual device. (Even though it said I already owned it, couldn't make changes without admin approval)
Once app was downloaded, signed out all devices, waited awhile to make sure they most likely logged in before me, and when I logged in, I was able to retrieve all data from "my" connected computer.   Giving me owners full address book, IMEI number, Gmail account info search history, etc.
So, 9/10 most likely no one is hacking your phone.  But there's always that 10th time.

Good Luck